# Postmeta not saving

Tags: php, functions, post-meta

I'm created a postmeta box but it doesn't appear to be saving anything to the DB. I'm check in  wp_postmeta and there is nothing there relevant to this metabox.

I believe it is something wrong with the nonce due to the `die` error been displayed.

question: What is causing my metabox not to save to the database therefore not allowing me to output the results.

here is my code that creates/saves the metabox.

```
<?php
// Add the Meta Box  
function ge_add_subtitle_meta_box() {  
    add_meta_box(  
        'excerpt_meta_box', // $id  
        'Excerpt Meta Box', // $title   
        'ge_show_subtitle_meta_box', // $callback  
        'page', // $page  
        'normal', // $context  
        'high'); // $priority  
}  

//hook the function to add meta boxes
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'ge_add_subtitle_meta_box');  

// Field Array  
$prefix = 'getextra';  
$custom_meta_fields = array(  
    array(
        'label' => 'Subtitle',
        'desc'  => 'Insert a small description of the page underneath this title.',  
        'id'    => $prefix.'subtitle',  
        'type'  => 'textarea' 
        )
);  

// The Callback  
function ge_show_subtitle_meta_box() {  
//make array globalscope and call $post to acces global array
global $custom_meta_fields, $post;  
// Use nonce for verification  
echo '<input type="hidden" name="subtitle_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';  

    // Begin the field table and loop  
    echo '<table class="form-table">';  
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {  
        // get value of this field if it exists for this post  
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);  
        // begin a table row with  
        echo '<tr> 
                <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th> 
                <td>';  
                switch($field['type']) {  
                    // case items will go here  
                    // text  
case 'text':  
    echo '<input type="text" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$meta.'" size="30" /> 
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
break;  
// textarea  
case 'textarea':  
    echo '<textarea name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" cols="60" rows="4">'.$meta.'</textarea> 
        <br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
break; 
// checkbox  
case 'checkbox':  
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'" ',$meta ? ' checked="checked"' : '','/> 
        <label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['desc'].'</label>';  
break; 
// select  
case 'select':  
    echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'" id="'.$field['id'].'">';  
    foreach ($field['options'] as $option) {  
        echo '<option', $meta == $option['value'] ? ' selected="selected"' : '', ' value="'.$option['value'].'">'.$option['label'].'</option>';  
    }  
    echo '</select><br /><span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>';  
break;  
                } //end switch  
        echo '</td></tr>';  
    } // end foreach  
    echo '</table>'; // end table  
}  

// Save the Data  
function getextra_save_subtitle_meta($post_id) {  
    global $custom_meta_fields;  

    // verify nonce  
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['subtitle_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id; } else { die( 'failed to verify nonce' ); }

    // check autosave  
    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE)  
        return $post_id;  

    // check permissions  
    if ('page' == $_POST['post_type']) {  
        if (!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id))  
            return $post_id;  
        } elseif (!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {  
            return $post_id;  
    }  

    // loop through fields and save the data  
    foreach ($custom_meta_fields as $field) {  
        $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], true);  
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];  
        if ($new && $new != $old) {  
            update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);  
        } elseif ('' == $new && $old) {  
            delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);  
        }  
    } // end foreach  
}  
//hook into save the post
add_action('save_post', 'ge_save_subtitle_meta');    
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This part:

```
// verify nonce  
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['subtitle_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
    return $post_id; } else { die( 'failed to verify nonce' ); }
```

should be:

```
// verify nonce  
if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['subtitle_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
    return; 
}
```

Comment: I'm now trying to echo out the code and its not displaying I'm using    <?php
          $desc = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'excerpt_meta_box', true );
            // check if the custom field has a value
            if( ! empty( $desc ) ) {
              echo $desc;
            } else {
              echo 'This is not display the custom text';
            }
          ?>

Comment: print this and add the result: `var_dump(get_post_meta( get_the_ID()));`

Comment: Thats this led me to find I was using the wrong ID :D

Comment: For the record and other people's brains why can you not return $post_id?

Comment: Since nonce verification failed, what I just need is to stop these data to be saved. What should be done with the `$post_id`?